# Azure worker role failed to start due to "System.IO.FileNotFoundException"

Tags: azure

My Azure worker role runs well in Local Development environment, but just won't start in Azure.
It reports the following error and keeps restarting.

```
Role has encountered an error and has stopped. Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
```

How can I know which file is not found?

If this error happens on my local box, I usually check for any assembly binding failures. But I am not sure how can I troubleshoot this in Azure.

I am using VS2013 with Azure SDK 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my worker role is actually looking for a file, which I mis-configure its name in the *.cscfg file. It's indeed a FileNotFound error.